# How to call a restlet asynchronously in Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite

Can anyone tell me out to call a restlet asynchronously from a suitelet in Netsuite?.

I tried using nlapiRequestURL, but unable to make asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot make async calls using the `nlapiRequestURL` on the server-side. The async version of `nlapiRequestURL` is client-side only.

SuiteScript 2.0 has several `promise` APIs for async calls, but they are only available client-side as well.